# Fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 on desktop system will not shutdown. Why?

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown

I've recently made the switch on my desktop system to Kubuntu 14.04 after years of using Microsoft Windows. The issue I am having is after fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 my system will not completely shutdown now I have to press and hold power button to make the machine go off. I have done some research online and tried many different methods to resolve this issue but to no avail, no matter what I try the issue still remains. Can anyone please help me?

System Specs:

1 x 1 T.B.Desktop Hard Disc Drive S.A.T.A @ 7200 R.P.M.,

1 x 24x S.A.T.A. DVD Writer Optical Drive

Intel DG33BU Socket LGA775 motherboard

Motherboard Essentials:

Status  End of Interactive Support

Launch Date     Q2'07

Board Form Factor   microATX

Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type)  8 GB

Memory Types    DDR2-800/677

Number of Memory Channels   2

Number of DIMMs Slots   4

ECC Memory Supported ‡  No

Using this:

System RAM (Memory) DDR2-800 PC2-6400 800MHz. x 2   2 G.B.ea.x 2 @ 4 G.B. Total

Integrated Graphics ‡   Yes   (Not being used.)

Graphics Output     VGA

Number of Displays Supported ‡  2

Discrete Graphics   PCIe x16

Using this addon adapter:

Nvidia GeForce GT 610 Palit 2GB DDR3

Core Speed  810 MHz help icon   Transistor Size 40nm

Architecture    Fermi GF119 help icon   Texture Mapping Units   8

SLI/Crossfire Support   no  Texture Rate    6.5 GTexel/s

Dedicated   no  Render Output Units 4

Release Date    01 May 2012 Pixel Rate  3.2 GPixel/s

Memory  2048MB  DirectX 11

Memory Speed    535MHz  Shader Model    5.0

Memory Bus  64 Bit  Open GL Version 4.2

Memory Type DDR3    Max Resolution  2560x1600

Memory Bandwidth    8.6 GB/sec  HDMI Connections    1

SPUs    48  DVI Connections 1

SPU Performance 96  VGA Connections 1

Expansion Options:

PCI Support     2

PCIe x1 Gen 2.x     1

PCIe x4 Gen 2.x     0

PCIe x8 Gen 2.x     0

PCIe x16 Gen 2.x    1

I/O Specifications:

USB 2.0 Configuration (Back + Internal)     6+6

Total Number of SATA Ports  4

Number of eSATA Ports   0

RAID Configuration  N/A

Number of PATA Ports    1

Number of Parallel Ports    0

Number of Serial Ports  1

Audio (back channel + front channel)    6-ch

Integrated LAN  10/100/1000

Firewire    1+1

Package Specifications:

Max CPU Configuration   1

Advanced Technologies:

Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) ‡  No

Intel® vPro Technology ‡    No

Intel® ME Firmware Version  N/A

Intel® Remote Wake Technology   No

Intel® Remote PC Assist Technology  No

Intel® CIRA Technology  No

TPM     No

Intel® Quiet System Technology  Yes

Intel® HD Audio Technology  No

Intel® Matrix Storage Technology    No

Intel® Platform Protection Technology:

Trusted Execution Technology ‡  No

Anti-Theft Technology   No

Using this C.P.U.:

Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q6600

(8M Cache, 2.40 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)

Essentials:

Status  End of Life

Launch Date     Q1'07

Processor Number    Q6600

Number of Cores     4

Clock Speed     2.4 GHz

L2 Cache    8 MB

FSB Speed   1066 MHz

FSB Parity  No

Instruction Set     64-bit

Embedded Options Available None

Lithography     65 nm

Max TDP     105 W

VID Voltage Range   0.8500V-1.500V

Package Specifications:

TCASE   B3=62.2°C; G0=71°C

Package Size    37.5mm x 37.5mm

Processing Die Size     286 mm2

Number of Processing Die Transistors    582 million

Sockets Supported   LGA775

Low Halogen Options Available

Advanced Technologies:

Intel® Turbo Boost Technology ‡     No

Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology ‡   No

Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ‡   Yes

Intel® 64 ‡   Yes

Idle States     Yes

Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology   Yes

Intel® Demand Based Switching   No

Thermal Monitoring Technologies     Yes

Intel® Data Protection Technology

AES New Instructions   No

Intel® Platform Protection Technology

Trusted Execution Technology ‡   No

Execute Disable Bit ‡   Yes

Answer (score 1):

I am also very new to Ubuntu world, but what i can suggest is you check in system settings the power option. Check it carefully because may be some setting there might be preventing your system from shutting down.